# Why in finding PDF of e^X in terms of the PDF of X,which is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1, the answer is 1/y, rather than 1/(2y)?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

The question here is: "Find the PDF of e^x in terms of PDF of X. Specialize the answer to the case where X is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 (Problem 4.1 of the book "Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition"). Using the fact that px(x) is 1/2 (1/(1-0+1) = 1/2), I come out with 1/2y for fy(y). However, the solution is only 1/y. What have I missed or done wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ takes values in $[0,1]$, $Y=e^X$ takes values in $[1,e]$. For $1\leqslant t\leqslant e$ we have
$$\mathbb P(e^{X}\leqslant t) = \mathbb P(X\leqslant \log t),
$$
so the density of $Y$ is obtained by differentiating: $f_Y(y) = \frac 1y\cdot\mathsf 1_{[1,e]}(t)$.

Comment: Don't you think that three false equalities is already too much?

Comment: @NCh I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pdf of uniform distribution on $(0,\,1)$ is ($a=0$, $b=1$), $0\leqslant x \leqslant 1$
$$
p_X(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}=\frac{1}{1-0}= 1.
$$

Comment: I am a little confused between discrete uniform distribution and continuous uniform distribution. The reason is that for discrete uniform distribution, pX(x) = 1/(b-a+1).

Comment: @AmosKu After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).